# Foreign Language for Text Inputs

Tags: internationalization, translation

I am making a site in Russian language. This is first time, I am working on site in foreign language. For administration sections, I have to make the html form so that we can enter text in Russian language in textfield and textareas.
Can you please let me know how do I make this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unicode:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Basically, nothing else needs to be done. (Except to do the same to the database, if you use one.)

Even when not making a Russian site, you should really be using Unicode; people can have weird names, news stories might be talking about funny places, movies sometimes have wacky titles...

Answer (score 0):

The text input elements will accept Russian characters (or any language, for that matter). The user being able to input those characters is not really something you can control. If the user has a Russian keyboard or keyboard layout, then they will naturally enter Russian characters.

Comment: What about default values for textfields like "Site Search", "Your email" etc....?

Comment: Any sort of default values will need to be specified by your site itself and isn't so much a page configuration or set up as it is a server-side programming issue. Web site localization is an entirely different (and not simple) issue that is beyond the scope of this particular question.